# Play fmod event sounds in 3D

Tags: iphone, fmod

I have an event called Numbers. In Fmod Designer the event plays different numbers depending on listenerAngle. I want to be able to hear the different sounds when I position this event in a 3D space. This is the code I have at the moment. It only plays one of the numbers in my app. Am I missing something?

```
FMOD_RESULT         result     = FMOD_OK;
    FMOD_VECTOR         listenerpos;
    FMOD_VECTOR         forward         = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    FMOD_VECTOR         up              = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
    FMOD_VECTOR         vel             = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

    result = group->getEvent("Numbers", FMOD_EVENT_DEFAULT, &event);
        ERRCHECK(result);

    listenerpos.x = 0.436243;
    listenerpos.y = -0.43643;
    listenerpos.z = -6;

    result = eventSystem->set3DListenerAttributes(0, &listenerpos, &vel, &forward, &up);
    ERRCHECK(result);
```

Help is very much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some lines and got it working. I had to place out the event in the 3D world.

```
FMOD_RESULT    result = FMOD_OK;
FMOD_VECTOR    listenerpos = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
FMOD_VECTOR    eventpos        = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
float DISTANCEFACTOR          = 2.0f;

result = group->getEvent("Numbers", FMOD_EVENT_DEFAULT, &event);
ERRCHECK(result);

listenerpos.x = 0;
listenerpos.y = 0;
listenerpos.z = 0;    

result = eventSystem->set3DListenerAttributes(0, &listenerpos,NULL,NULL,NULL);
ERRCHECK(result);

eventpos.x = xPos; // Object's x position on iPhone I move around
eventpos.z = yPos;


result = event->set3DAttributes(&eventpos2,&vel);
ERRCHECK(result);

result = eventSystem->update();
ERRCHECK(result);

result = ballEvent->start();
ERRCHECK(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your "Numbers" event is 2D? Can you check and ensure it's 3D.

Comment: The sound is 3D but I had to add these lines and now it works:                     eventpos.x = xPos;
eventpos.z = yPos;
    

    result = event->set3DAttributes(&eventpos2,&vel);
    ERRCHECK(result);